# Texture loading in three.js with css sprites

Tags: html, css, three.js

I am using

> var texture1 = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("image1.jpg");
>   to map this texture to a material.

My query is that can I load texture by css as I want to load images by css sprites. I need to give background position with every texture which is not possible if I load textures via html.
I need to use background : url() property.

Please let me know how it can be done

Answer (score 0):

The thing to note here is that your entire Three.js scene is being rendered on an HTML Canvas. That said you now exist in a purely GDI based environment. The only solution I can see for you now is to remap your materials texture calling an update pointing to a new "2d" canvas context. Something like this:

```
var spriteCanvas = document.createElement( "canvas" );
var spriteContext = spriteCanvas.getContext( "2d" );
var spriteImage = document.getElementById( "hidden_spriteDiv_with_background_url" );
spriteContext.drawImage( spriteImage, 0, 0 );

var texture1 = new THREE.Texture( spriteContext );
texture1.needsUpdate = true;
```

Then assigning the new Texture map "texture1" to your material with applicable updates called. Hope that at least gets you started.